# Can't convert one page tiff to pdf

Tags: powershell, file-conversion

The code below uses `nconvert` to merge multiple `tiff` images into one `pdf` file.  My issue is: whenever one "document or pdf file" is supposed to contain only one tiff image, the script will crash.  If anyone can take a look at the script, and has any ideas on why this might be the case, it would be greatly appreciated.

```
$InputLocation = "C:\Convert" 
$output = "C:\Convert"   
$Inputbdf = "C:\Convert\0001.bdf"


$patternCN = "\|([^\|]*)\|([^\|]*)\|"
$patternD = "(\d)/\d\d/(\d\d\d\d)"

$docs = gci "$inputLocation\*0001.tif"
$docs.count
foreach($tiff in $docs){
    $pattern = $tiff.FullName.Substring($tiff.FullName.length-12,4)
    $patternI = "$pattern.*"
    $pages = gci "$inputLocation\$pattern*.tif"

    $pagen = $pages.count    

    $lines = Get-Content($inputbdf)|
    Foreach-object{
       write-host $PatternI
        if($_ -match "C:\\[some folder]\\$patternI.TIF$patternCN$patternD"){
         $a = $matches[2]
         $b = $matches[1]
         $c = $matches[4]
         $d = $matches[3]   

        }

    }

    if((test-path -path "$output\$c") -eq $false){
        New-Item $output\$c -type directory

        if((test-path -path "$output\$c\$d") -eq $false){
             new-Item $output\$c\$d -type directory    
        }
    }     

    $tiff = $tiff.Name.split('.')[0]
    cd C:\[my desktop folder]\Nconvert\XnView 
    #./nconvert -help > nchelp.txt 
   .\nconvert.exe -quiet -out pdf -c 3 -multi -n 1 $pagen 1 -o "$output\$c\$d\$a$b.pdf" "$InputLocation\$pattern####.tif"


 }
```

Comment: It would greatly help if you mentioned what tool you are using to merge the tiff files...

Comment: nconvert.  The last line in the script is the part of the script that does the actual conversion.

Comment: Your assignments to `$matches`,what's going on there? I don't know much about tiff conversion, but I do code and know about powershell, so gimmie the details.

Comment: Well i am new to coding so i will try and explain best i can.  The Matches has to do with the naming of the file and the output path. The number corresponds to each spot in the array that is created by the -match parameter.  Where the patterns are spelled out at the top, the groups that have parentheses around them represent one place in the array.

Comment: Can you post the error that you are receiving?

Comment: GS: (C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.07\bin\gsdll64.dll)
ARG 0 -dNODISPLAY 
ARG 1 -dQUIET 
ARG 2 -sPDFname=C:\Convert\2013\6\JJF555.pdf 
ARG 3 -sDSCname=C:\Users\PMANCA~1.SCE\AppData\Local\Temp\x_8AD5.tmp 
ARG 4 pdf2dsc.ps 
ARG 5 -c quit 
==> 134

Comment: ERROR: -101 
GS: (C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.07\bin\gsdll64.dll)
ARG 0 -dBATCH 
ARG 1 -dFirstPage=1 
ARG 2 -dLastPage=1 
ARG 3 -dMaxBitmap=300000000 
ARG 4 -sDEVICE=tiff24nc 
ARG 5 -q 
ARG 6 -dNOPAUSE 
ARG 7 -dSAFER 
ARG 8 -dTextAlphaBits=4 
ARG 9 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 
ARG 10 -g611x791 
ARG 11 -r72x72 
ARG 12 -sOutputFile=C:\Users\PMANCA~1.SCE\AppData\Local\Temp\x_8B63.tmp 
ARG 13 C:\Convert\2013\6\JJF555.pdf 
ARG 14 -c quit 
ARG 15 -c quit